# How to release an AAR with another android library project dependency?

Tags: android, maven, gradle, aar

Here is my development project structure:

```
projectFolder
  |
  +--App
  |
  +--MyLib
  |
  +--Libraries
      |
      +--LibA
```

*MyLib* depends on LibA, I have packaged *MyLib* as an AAR and release it to a Maven repo, But when I include *MyLib* in another project(*TestProj*) as a remote aar dependency, I get build error(can't resolve dependency of *LibA*, *LibA* is not included with the release of *MyLib*), 
This is the build.gradel in app folder of *TestProj*:

```
dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  compile ('xxx.xxxxxx:yyyyy:1.0-SNAPSHOT@aar'){
      transitive = true
  }
}
```

And here is the build.gradle of *MyLib*:

```
dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  compile project(':Libraries:LibA')
}
```

How can I release *MyLib* with *LibA* already packaged in the AAR?

Comment: Running into the same problem.  Any luck?

Comment: @lostintranslation , I post a answer, hope it helps.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Answer the question myself. finally I changed the *build.gradle* in *MyLib* to:

```
dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  provided project(':Libraries:LibA')
}
```

so *LibA* will only be used in the build process of *MyLib*, *TestProj* will not ask for the *LibA* dependency anymore at compile time. NOTE THAT this may cause NoClassDefFoundError at runtime, so you must told the guys who used your library to include the LibA themselves in build.gradle of their project.

At first, I was looking for a method to package *LibA* with *MyLib*, but it seems diffcult.

See this question: [Android Studio how to package single AAR from multiple library projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20700581/android-studio-how-to-package-single-aar-from-multiple-library-projects)

Comment: MyLib's POM should have LibA declared as a dependency, which should solve the problem.

Comment: LibA is a Library project and it is not on maven central, if other people want to use MyLib, how can gradle auto resolve the dependency?

Comment: It should be published to some public or internal Maven repository. If this is an OSS project, Bintray offers a personal Maven repo for free.

Comment: its 'provided', not 'provide', but this is apparently too short to be an edit.

Comment: So there is no way of attaching an .aar code sources in your lib also released as .aar ?