# Transitive dependencies for local aar library

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, aar

We're making some library, basicly for our API, that we would make life easier for our external developers.

So we created new library project and put Retrofit and some other libraries as dependencies.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'
}
```

Now when we build it, it produces `aar` file.

But now when we put the `aar` file to `libs` directory and set it as dependency, we still have to put the same dependency in user's `build.gradle` file, which sucks. It should be taken from the library, right?

```
repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile(name: 'ourlibrary', ext: 'aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}
```

How to make `transitive = true` work?

Comment: Looking for a solution for the exact same problem, how did you end up with this?

Comment: hi, are you able to solve the issue?

Comment: Hey, how did you solve this?

Comment: By putting the dependencies to README :-(

Answer (score 70, accepted):

The **aar** file **doesn't contain the nested (or [transitive](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Transitive_Dependencies)) dependencies** and doesn't have a pom file which describes the dependencies used by the library.

It means that, if you are importing a aar file using a `flatDir` repo you have to specify the dependencies also in your project.

In your case adding `transitive=true` doesn't resolve your issue for the reason described above.

You should use a **maven repository** (you have to publish the library in a private or public maven repo), you will not have the same issue.
In this case, gradle downloads the dependencies using the pom file which will contains the dependencies list.

Comment: could you elaborate on "you have to specify the dependencies also in your project"

Comment: Finally got here. It seems you have to publish it to somewhere to make the `transitive` work.

Comment: publish to mavenLocal. The transitive for AAR not working.

Comment: `*aar file doesn't contain the nested (or transitive) dependencies*` is that true for any local `libs` folder directory of the Android Library? Or is it for dependencies added via `gradle`?

Comment: @Abbas I'm looking for a proper solution for this, as I'd like to distribute a library in one file. So far the only solution I've found is creating a fat aar. However this can mess up other dependencies in the host app, so be careful if you decide to use it.


Here's a link a for script that does this: https://github.com/adwiv/android-fat-aar


Also an explanation why it's a bad idea: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28605367/library-with-bundles-dependencies-fat-aar