# How create an aar library including jar dependencies

Tags: java, android, maven, android-studio, aar

I'm deploying an aar lib that contains two native libs and two jar wrappers. 
To "hide" the wrappers I imported this jars to my local maven repository with **mvn install:install-file -Dfile=myjar1.jar -DgroupId=com.my.package -DartifactId=engine -Dversion=1.1.1 -Dpackaging=jar** and reference it inside the lib project. 
But if I don't reference this wrapper jars in the application project too I just found NoClassDefFoundError when try to use any class of this jars. Anybody know how can I do solve that avoiding to populate and add dependencies of this jars in the app project?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36916991/transitive-dependencies-for-local-aar-library

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transitive dependencies for local aar library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36916991/transitive-dependencies-for-local-aar-library)