# Android Library issue

Tags: android

I'm trying to create an `Android library` for two days already.
Realy need your help.
I have an existing `App` which I want to do as a `Library`.

According to `Android` developers documentation:

> f you have an existing app module with all the code you want to reuse,
>   you can turn it into a library module as follows:
>
> Open the module-level build.gradle file. Delete the line for the
>   applicationId. Only an Android app module can define this. At the top
>   of the file, you should see the following: apply plugin:
>   'com.android.application' Change it to the following: apply plugin:
>   'com.android.library'

**I have done this step.
The next step is saying:**

> When you want to build the AAR file, select the library module in the
>   Project window and then click Build > Build APK.

I don't really understand how to build the AAR file.
Also in my library, I have others `dependencies` which I need to be in my Library.

I tried a lot of suggestions in **StackOverflow** but didn't find the answer.

Unfortunately, I didn't find a good example of creating an `Android Library` with `dependencies`.

Comment: `don't vote down.` why? is there a single reason that your question is special, or you are special somehow?

Comment: also `dependencies which I need to be in my Library` is bad idea. What if there will be multiple libraries with same dependencies built in? How to resolve conflicts? It is too complicated.

Comment: What would you like to do with your library? Publish it for others to use or just use it in your own app?

Comment: I'm building it for a customer. He will use it in his App.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't really understand how to build the AAR file

Just compile the library or use `./gradlew build`.
The output will be stored under the library's subdirectory under `build/outputs/aar`.

> I have others dependencies which I need to be in my Library.

The aar file doesn't contain the [transitive dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36916991/transitive-dependencies-for-local-aar-library/36931247#36931247).
I suggest you publishing your library into a public or private maven repository.

Comment: So, there is no way to create a library with external libraries inside?

Comment: @IgorFridman If others should use it, you should avoid to try it. The best way is to use a maven repo. In this way who uses your library can manage dependencies and conflicts.