# Creating fat AAR file in Android Studio

Tags: android

I want to know how to create fat AAR file in android studio.

For example I have project A as an Android library (.AAR) , which is dependent on 2 local modules projects M1 and M2 (included as

```
dependencies { 
compile project (m1) ...."
```

in build.gradle of library project A).

My questions are,

Q1. When I'm generating the .aar file of library A then how to include m1 and m2 inside the .aar file?

Q2. How to tell project B (android application which is including A.aar as dependency) to compile JCenter dependencies being used by m1 and m2?

Comment: See this question for an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28605367/library-with-bundles-dependencies-fat-aar

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve this by using maven repositories and adding m1 and m2 as dependency in *.pom file
`

```
<dependencies>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.android.databinding</groupId>
       <artifactId>baseLibrary</artifactId>
       <version>3.3.0</version>
       <scope>compile</scope>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.android.databinding</groupId>
       <artifactId>library</artifactId>
       <version>3.3.0</version>
       <scope>compile</scope>
   </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

`

more about maven dependencies in https://maven.apache.org/pom.html

Answer (score 0):

Android Gradle plugin does not officially support this. But you can use a plugin like this.
https://github.com/Mobbeel/fataar-gradle-plugin