# How to compile libs/*.jar ,dependenced libraries and my java/kotlin code file into dex in library module?

Tags: android, android-studio, jar, build.gradle, dex

I want to compile libs/*.jar, dependent libraries and my java/kt code file into dex in **library module**, then the android app can download these dex files, then dynamically load them by DexClassLoader.

Android Studio provides a Gradle task "dexRelease" to compile my own code files into a dex file, but can not compile libs/*.jar and dependent libraries into dex file.

```
gradlew testsdk:dexRelease
```

I expect compile libs/*.jar, dependent libraries and my java/kt code file into dex in library module.

Comment: I'm assuming you're trying to achieve a fat-aar (which can be dexed). Have you seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28605367/1233652)?

Comment: Yes, I had seen many questions, but those questions don't quite meet my needs.  I actually only need the final dex file, with my own code, jar package, third-party dependencies inside.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with a way to achieve your requirement directly on a library module.

As a workaround, you can:

1. Write your code in a library (that is, built with **com.android.library** plugin) module.
2. Add an application module (that is, built with **com.android.application** plugin, without any sources or dependencies besides your library module) which will function as an wrapper around your library.
3. Build the project, and use its generated dex file.

---

I've created a [sample project](https://github.com/alipov/q57441198) to illustrate that.
The project structure is the following (I've omitted irrelevant files):

```
├── app  
│   ├── build.gradle  
│   └── src  
│       └── main  
│           └── AndroidManifest.xml  
└── testsdk  
    ├── build.gradle  
    └── src  
        └── main  
            ├── AndroidManifest.xml  
            └── java  
                └── info  
                    └── osom  
                        └── testsdk  
                            └── TestClass.java
```

**testsdk** is a library module, **app** is a library wrapper module. `TestClass.java` is a sample source file, similar to source files included in your library module.

Both `AndroidManifest.xml` files contain the bare minimum functionality, i.e. `app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` content is:

```
<manifest package="info.osom.q57441198"/>
```

**testsdk**'s `build.gradle` file includes a sample dependency, just to simulate your library's dependencies.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'  

android {  
    compileSdkVersion 28  
}  

dependencies {  
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.7.1'  
}
```

Wrapper's (**app**) module `build.gradle` file adds a dependency on library module:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'  

android {  
    compileSdkVersion 28  
    defaultConfig {  
        minSdkVersion 21  
    }  
}  

dependencies {  
    implementation project(':testsdk')  
}
```

Build the project using:
`$ ./gradlew clean assembleRelease`
and then find the generated dex file under `app/build/intermediates/dex/release/mergeDexRelease/out/classes.dex`.

You can use [baksmali](https://github.com/JesusFreke/smali/wiki) to verify all your library sources and library's dependencies are bundled inside the dex:

```
$ baksmali classes.dex  
$ tree out  
out
├── info
│   └── osom
│       ├── q57441198
│       │   ├── BuildConfig.smali
│       │   └── R.smali
│       └── testsdk
│           ├── BuildConfig.smali
│           ├── R.smali
│           └── TestClass.smali
├── org
│   ├── intellij
│   │   └── lang
│   │       └── annotations
│   │           ├── Flow.smali
│   │           ├── // redacted...
│   │           └── Subst.smali
│   └── jetbrains
│       └── annotations
│           ├── Async$Execute.smali
│           ├── // redacted...
│           └── TestOnly.smali
└── timber
    └── log
        ├── R.smali
        ├── Timber$1.smali
        ├── Timber$DebugTree.smali
        ├── Timber$Tree.smali
        └── Timber.smali
```

The only overhead the wrapper (**app**) module adds to the dex file are the following two classes: `info/osom/q57441198/BuildConfig.smali` and `info/osom/q57441198/R.smali`. You can simply disregard them. If you insist on removing them, there are [tools](https://github.com/JesusFreke/smali/tree/master/dexlib2) to help you with that.

Comment: That's a great answer!