# How to export AAR including its dependencies?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have an Android Studio library project which uses `library.aar` and `library.jar`. When I export it as `mylib.aar` and use this new AAR into a different app/project, it cannot find the classes defined in the `library.aar` and `library.jar`.

My `build.gradle` looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile project(':library_dot_aar')
    compile project(':library_dot_jar')
}
```

I imported the AAR and JAR files in Android Studio using `New -> Module -> Import .JAR or .AAR Package` and add them as dependencies in `Project Structure -> Module Settings -> Dependencies -> Add Module Dependencies`.

When I unzipped `mylib.aar` it was only 25KB (considering `library.aar` was over 300KB, I assume `mylib.aar`'s size would be in the same range) and the included dependencies were not included in it. How do I export an AAR that includes all its dependencies inside itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20700581/android-studio-how-to-package-single-aar-from-multiple-library-projects):

> There is no mechanism to combine library. It's a bit complicated as
>   you probably want to control which dependencies get merged (for
>   instance you probably don't want to include support-v4 in there). Also
>   you'd need to merge the resources and Android manifest.
>
> At this time there's no way to easily hack something, unless you are
>   sure the resources have no conflicts between the two res folders (for
>   instance you could have strings_a.xml in one lib and strings_b.xml in
>   the other lib). This way you can just "merge" the two res folders by
>   copying them both into the same location (as opposed to do a merge at
>   the android res level).
>
> For the Manifest it'd be more complicated, but doable with some custom
>   code.
>
> Providing a built-in mechanism for this is very low on our priority so
>   don't expect it anytime soon.

Comment: Thanks. I found a work around by including both the `library.aar` and `library.jar` in the other project, along with `mylib.aar`.

Comment: Hi alxcy, did u found any method to make aar including dependency url and jar and lib. It will sure help us