# Generate a single AAR file from multiple internal Android library modules

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, aar

I have the following structure for my project:

> ```
> LibD(JNI) ---- LibC --- LibA -----|
>                                   |----MyLibrary
>                         LibB -----|
> ```
>
> MyLibrary depends on LibA and LibB
>
> LibA depends on LibC
>
> LibC depends on LibD which is a native library

I need to generate a single AAR file for MyLibrary that includes all other libraries and .so files from LibD using Gradle so I can put it on a maven repo

Note: These are not 3rd party libraries and I have the source code. I needed to separate them for reusability.

I have already tried the following, but it generates a separate .AAR files for each module

> build.gradle - MyLibrary
>
> ```
> apply plugin: 'android-library'
> dependencies {
>     compile project(':LibA')
>     compile project(':LibB')
> }
> ```
>
> build.gradle - LibA
>
> ```
> apply plugin: 'android-library'
> dependencies {
>     compile project(':LibC')
> }
> ```
>
> build.gradle - LibC
>
> ```
> apply plugin: 'android-library'
> dependencies {
>     compile project(':LibD')
> }
> ```

Any help/suggestion would be appreciated.

**** I've already looked at [Android Studio how to package single AAR from multiple library projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20700581/android-studio-how-to-package-single-aar-from-multiple-library-projects) but since its an old topic I'm posting the question again

Comment: AFAIK, the accepted answer in the mentioned question still holds. There's no mechanism to produce a single aar. You can write it yourself. But it's not a simple task.

Comment: At the time, the arguments were that it is not easy to merge Manifests and resources. However, we now have a Manifest merger and a resource merger. So I don't know what is still a blocker for this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio how to package single AAR from multiple library projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20700581/android-studio-how-to-package-single-aar-from-multiple-library-projects)