# Create aar file from multiple libraries

Tags: android, gradle, aar

I need to create aar file for an android library. We have two other libraries which needs to integrated with main library as source code or .aar files. Dont know how to create single aar file which depends on other local libraries. Please Help.

Need to create aar for LibraryA which depends on LibraryB and  LibraryC.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio how to package single AAR from multiple library projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20700581/android-studio-how-to-package-single-aar-from-multiple-library-projects)

Comment: @bummi Yes. There is no correct answer to solve this issue. Hope will get some solution.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem right, you can solve it by using fat-aar:
https://github.com/adwiv/android-fat-aar