# What is Assets.car file in .app?

Tags: macos, cocoa

I was looking at the contents of my application and I found the file Assets.car in the resources folder of my application along with some nibs:

[image: Assets.car file]

My question is: What is this file and what does it have to do with the application? What kind of data does it contain?

Comment: I would assume that it is the `assets.catalog` https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/Recipe.html

Comment: These days, the link to the above is at https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/8.0/#/dev10510b1f7

Comment: [developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/managing-assets-with-asset-catalogs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/managing-assets-with-asset-catalogs)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is the "compiled" version of the assets catalog.

Answer (score 0):

**Assets.car file**

When you build a project all your non empty assets `.xcassets` which are added to `Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources` will be compiled into `Assets.car` file, which is generated by Xcode during building and set up by `Build Settings -> Asset Catalog Compiler`

[[Open Assets.car]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61040369/4770877)