# Analysing Assets.car file in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, ios6

I have trying to reduce the overall size of my iOS application which is currently 48MB. When I analyze sub folders, I found Assets.car is taking 41MB. I am not able to open and see which one is taking that much space.

I couldn't find any good documentation regarding Assets.car file. Can someone suggest how to view the contents?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is Assets.car file in .app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20777488/what-is-assets-car-file-in-app)

Comment: @borrrden, this doesn't answer my question. I am looking for analyzing which part is taking more memory.

Comment: @rajeevprasanna i think this file contains upscaled images for iphone 6 too!

Answer (score 110, accepted):

This tool can extract a .car archive: https://github.com/steventroughtonsmith/cartool

**Steps to extract archive:**

Once you've downloaded the zip from github, compile it in Xcode to generate the command line tool. Then expand the `Products` group and right click on the `cartool` file and  locate it in finder. You can then run the tool like so:

- open terminal
- `cd /path/to/cartool`
- `./cartool /path/to/Assets.car /path/to/outputDirectory`

Comment: I downloaded this tool but I don't know how to use it? Where is the output files?

Comment: I've added some extra info to the answer with brief running instructions. Maybe if you get it working you could update the readme.md for other people in your shoes.

Comment: I do following your instruction but it said: cartool: cannot execute binary file. Please advice. Thanks.

Comment: I found it. Need to run with this command ./cartool Assets.car outputDirectory. Many thanks Lewis42.

Comment: ./cartool /Users/way1/Desktop/Assets.car /Users/way1/Desktop/Image\ assests 
-bash: ./cartool: is a directory ... can you help me in this it was showing cartool is a directory...

Comment: getting error can not execute binary file, can you provide exact script ? In terminal i am at the path of cartool-master.

Comment: cartool paritoshraval$  /Users/paritoshraval/Desktop/Assets.car  /Users/paritoshraval/Desktop/SwiftCodesclear             
                                       
-bash: /Users/paritoshraval/Desktop/Assets.car: cannot execute binary file

Comment: it crashed when i tried to use it to open .car file built by xCode, Version 8.0 beta 6 (8S201h) `Assertion failed: (tokenCount < maxCountIncludingZeroTerminator - 1), function CUIRenditionKeySetValueForAttribute, file /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/CoreUI/CoreUI-366.1/CoreTheme/ThemeStorage/CUIThemeRendition_Support.m, line 228.
`

Comment: Couple of issues. 1) It lists the files contained in `Assets.car` but at the end the `output folder` is empty. 2) You rerun the command and it gives you `Segmentation fault: 11`.

Comment: @adeel probably best to raise an issue at https://github.com/steventroughtonsmith/cartool

Comment: This tool doesn't work with newer .car files (from ios11 SDK)

Answer (score 125):

Run Apple’s assetutil:

```
xcrun --sdk iphoneos assetutil --info Assets.car
```

you’ll get a JSON description of each item in the file. Something like this:

```
  {
    "Height" : 60,
    "Scale" : 1,
    "RenditionName" : "D3801CE9-19F1-4CE9-97C6-7E1EFFFCAE89",
    "AssetType" : "Vector",
    "SizeOnDisk" : 10822,
    "Name" : "mailbox",
    "Idiom" : "universal",
    "Width" : 99
  },
```

Note the line `"SizeOnDisk" : 10822`.

This tool performs limited .car manipulation, run `man assetutil` for details.

---

The Assets.car seems to be a proprietary Apple’s archive that first appeared in iOS 7. A few utilities are able to extract its contents using the private class `CUICatalog` of the CoreUI framework:

- [acextract](https://github.com/bartoszj/acextract)
- [ThemeEngine](https://github.com/alexzielenski/ThemeEngine)
- [iOS Asset Extractor](https://github.com/Marxon13/iOS-Asset-Extractor)
- [Asset Catalog Tinkerer](https://github.com/insidegui/AssetCatalogTinkerer)

There is also an app that reads .car files: [crunch](https://pragmaticcode.com/crunch/) 9$, 15 day trial

Running `strings Assets.car` returned

```
@(#)PROGRAM:CoreUI  PROJECT:CoreUI-475.1.1
IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool-9.0
```

Running `find` inside Xcode-beta returned `/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Overlays/IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool`, which is a simulator executable (i386 + x86_64). Didn’t investigate any further but I bet that this tool could open .car archives if you run it inside the simulator.

Answer (score 91):

If you want to browse and extract asset catalogs, you can also use my app [Asset Catalog Tinkerer](https://github.com/insidegui/AssetCatalogTinkerer)

[image: Asset Catalog Tinkerer screenshot]

Comment: it crashed when i used release version 2.3 to open .car file built by xCode, Version 8.0 beta 6 (8S201h) `Assertion failed: (tokenCount < maxCountIncludingZeroTerminator - 1), function CUIRenditionKeySetValueForAttribute, file /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/CoreUI/CoreUI-366.1/CoreTheme/ThemeStorage/CUIThemeRendition_Support.m, line 228.`

Comment: @igrek Please open an issue on GitHub and include a sample file. Thanks.

Comment: I am sorry but this is a commercial project.. Do you believe it has anything to do with it's assets specifically? I tried the .cartool(http://stackoverflow.com/a/29468398/907692) and it has the same issue

Comment: There's probably something specific to the file which causes this problem. Without the file there's not much I can do...

Comment: @GuilhermeRambo I'm able to hit the exact error by trying to open Xcode 8's `Assets.car` file, located under `Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources`

Comment: @AllenZeng Thanks, I'll check it out.

Comment: Crashes on when opening my Xcode 8 assets.car, sadly.  Running assetutil on that .car returns Two of these errors: "Unable to create unsliced image from csi bitmap data."

Comment: Worked for me on 10.12.6 for touchbar assets in `/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemAppearance.bundle/Contents/Resources/Assets.car` - thanks!

Comment: I get the error `The document "Assets.car" could not be opened. Asset Catalog Tinkerer cannot open files in the "Compiled Xcode Catalog" format.`

Comment: Awesome tool. Works 100% on a brew cask install on macos high sierra

Comment: @GuilhermeRambo I am trying to get your NSAppearance tool to work, however it keeps crashing when trying to export the appearance. I can't figure out why though :-/ Could you help?

Comment: If I wanted to mess with a program, and modify the Assets.car file with different, but same sized images, how can I recompile/rearchive the extracted files back to Assets.car?  Or is this impossible of an endeavour without the source since I will need the nibs or the uncoupled storyboards in Xcode?

Comment: Very nice application to open .car files

Answer (score 6):

**Open Assets.car**

[[Assets.car file]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61040332/4770877)

You can try an [online tool(Assets.car Asset Extractor Online)](https://applicationloader.net/appicon.html), or a [QLCARFiles QuickLook plugin](https://blog.timac.org/2018/1112-quicklook-plugin-to-visualize-car-files/) for Mac

and to double check it use assetutil tool

```
xcrun --sdk iphoneos assetutil --info <path_to_Assets.car>
```

Comment: The plugin is great, thank you for the link!

Answer (score 2):

All the prior mentioned tools do not extract PDFs correctly. Within the [QLCARFiles](https://github.com/Timac/QLCARFiles) project there's a utility called `carDump` that does extract files correctly.

In short:

1. Clone the project from https://github.com/Timac/QLCARFiles
2. Open in xcode
3. Select the carDump scheme and build
4. Use the cli:

```
mkdir output
carDump Assets.car output
```

Answer (score 1):

Guilherme Rambo said is correct, not the Lewis42.

Suppose a pdf file('a.pdf') in Asserts.car.

You will get three png files(a.png/a@2x.png/a@3x.png) if using cartool, file format had been changed.

But, if you using AssetCatalogTinkerer, you can preview the a.pdf file(no file format changed).

Comment: But if you try to extract assets they are converted into PNGs, is there a way to extract them as PDF?

Answer (score 0):

Universal-binaries seem to contain multiple image resolutions for each screen-density.

Once the app is uploaded to the App Store the file-size will be less than your universal-binary, because each device will only get appropriate image densities.

You can check file-sizes here: iTunes Connect > My Apps > Your App > Activity > Your Build > App Store file-size