# How to use Xcode sidepanel icon images?

Tags: swift, xcode

When adding images to an NSButton I have noticed that there is no option for the Xcode style side panel buttons which are found in the top right of Xcode.
Whereabouts are these icons stored, and how can I use them for my own buttons?
[image: The button image I am referring to is circled in this image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to Stackoverflow!

Those images are built into the Xcode bundle and not available for the average developer to copy into their code.  [Other people have tried to do the same thing as you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45792729/nstoolbaritem-with-segmented-control-images-not-rendering-correctly), and so if you want to create a segmented control in your app's `NSToolbar`, why not incorporate publicly available graphics, like what you can find in [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/nicolas-miari/NSToolbarItem-Segment-Image-Issue), [specifically these assets](https://github.com/nicolas-miari/NSToolbarItem-Segment-Image-Issue/tree/master/ToolbarItemDemo/Assets.xcassets) that look like this:

[image: Left Pane]
[image: Right Pane]