# How does [UIImage imagedNamed:inBundle:compatibleWithTraitCollection:] actually access an image?

Tags: ios, uiimage, bundle

How does [UIImage imagedNamed:inBundle:compatibleWithTraitCollection:] actually access an image?

Take my framework as an example, the bundle address on product is `/Users/allenandkim/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/StraaS-ayuoelxoryhklegktulnazuqndzo/Build/Products/ReleaseCandidate-iphonesimulator/FooSDK.framework`, but there's `Asset.car` that is related to `.xcassets` in the folder.

I think `Asset.car` is the compiled file of `.xcassets`. Does `imagedNamed` access images from `Asset.car`? Or how does it access images from the bundle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To your question, yes.

`Asset.car` is archived *.xcassets. Check this thread, you can unarchive it back to xcasset with the tool it mentioned: [Analysing Assets.car file in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22630418/analysing-assets-car-file-in-ios)

Comment: Thank you, `Asset Catalog Tinkerer` is really useful.