Using HEIC image increasing the ipa size
In our project we've been utilizing PNG images from the xcassets folder which resulted in a total folder size of approximately 15MB. Consequently, our IPA size reached around 90MB. To mitigate this, we decided to optimize and switch to .heic images instead of .png. After converting all the images to .heic, we observed a reduction in the xcassets folder size to about 6MB. However, upon generating the IPA from these changes, the IPA file size unexpectedly increased, despite the xcassets file size decreasing by nearly 9MB.
What could be causing this discrepancy?

An IPA is just a ZIP file. Have you tried expanding the new bundle and figuring out what is growing the bundle. I wouldn’t be surprised if the archive process is recoding the images to another format.

Yes, i have extracted the ipa file and verified that .car file size is increased.

Dive deeper friend. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22630418/analysing-assets-car-file-in-ios

Thanks @WarrenBurton, this help me to read the .car file as json . But in that i just found that for single heic image there is 2 json objects, one with Encoding type as "ARGB" and next object with "HEIF".  For PNG images i can see for only one time.

For image formats other than jpeg and png what typically happens is that Xcode processes them at compile time to render different versions and this is what you are finding. So, often you end up with a larger ipa than if you had simply stuck with png. First, I would say that a 90mb IPA is not enormous snd you could just not worry about it.  If you do want to decrease the size, consider using on demand resources.

Thanks, @Paulw11, you're absolutely correct. I've relocated all the images to the bundle folder, eliminating the need for additional compression algorithms required for HEIC images in xcassets. As a result, I'm experiencing the expected reduction in IPA size. Much appreciated!
