# Link a bundle to a static library in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6

I'm trying to use an ImageAssets folder to a static library. 
I've read every post I could find about the process.
I was following [these steps from apple's guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/iOSStaticLibraries/iOSStaticLibraries.pdf)

My steps were:

1. Create a Resource folder in the project directory.
2. Renamed it as a .bundle
3. Added an ImageAssets folder into the bundle
4. Add it to the project
5. Add it the 'copy bundle resources' build phase

When I try to access an image inside:
    `UIImage* img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"BackLight"];`

it's not found.

- I've also tried to add ImageAssets folder directly to the project and add it to the 'copy bundle resources' phase with same results.

Additional info:

- Xcode 6.3.1
- Obj-C

Comment: Can you also post the code on how you are trying to access the image?

Comment: See your answer in below Link<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15331056/library-static-dynamic-or-framework-project-inside-another-project>

Comment: If you looked through a lot of similar questions you should have noticed the answers similar to the quote from the documentation that you linked: "Static libraries cannot include resources directly, but a static library project can provide resources which an application can reference and include in its Copy Bundle Resources phase". As for the image assets, I believe it should be added directly as opposed to be part of the resources bundle due to the need to preprocess the bundle - it isn't used simply as an images folder to be copied.