# Contradictory definitions of framework and library

Tags: ios, frameworks, static-libraries, cocoapods

I'm trying to make clear what is the difference between a `library` and a `framework`, in particular in `iOS` development, and I've been reading some blogs and posts and they give different explanations of them. For example, [CocoaPods](https://blog.cocoapods.org/CocoaPods-0.36/) describe them different from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15331056/library-static-dynamic-or-framework-project-inside-another-project).

I'd appreciate an updated and simple explanation of what a `library` and a `framework` are, and their main differences.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In Cocoa, a library is a single file, containing executable code that is linked during the build (static) or at runtime (dynamic). They have the extension `.dylib` (dynamic) or `.a` (static). Occasionally dynamic libraries will have the extension `.so`, particularly if they have a Unix history.

In Cocoa, a framework is a group of files in a directory structure, which will generally include a library, but may also include resources, other libraries, or even other frameworks. The directory has the extension `.framework`.

Occasionally frameworks will be called libraries as a generic term for "shared code." Occasionally libraries will be called frameworks as a generic term for "a unified infrastructure that the application relies on." But for Cocoa, the words generally refer to the packaging.