# I'm trying to add Cocoa Pod support for the custom swift framework. But, While running pod lib lint, there is a error related to static binary

Tags: swift, frameworks, cocoapods

I'm trying to add pod support to custom framework. I have added Speechkit as dependency in pod spec. while running `pod lib lint`, i'm getting following error message

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2FGm2.png)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Cocoapods is meant to provide easy support for dynamic frameworks being used during runtime. The problem described states, that SpeechKit is a static library which can't be used to provide a dynamic framework. The difference is good described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15331056/library-static-dynamic-or-framework-project-inside-another-project

Comment: What is your code spec ? and Which version of cocoa pods are using?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very sure about that, but it seems that until the static library dependency you rely on is changed into a dynamic framework, you have no other choice than waiting for it to happen : check [this issue](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/5624).