# is there need of static library to create framework?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Is this necessary to create static library for creation of framework or we can create it without help of static library what is diffrence betwwen them.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options for creating framework, one is static library (code is linked at compile time) and iOS8 onwards dynamic framework(code is linked at runtime). Refer to following answers for knowing the difference between them :

[Library? Static? Dynamic? Or Framework? Project inside another project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15331056/library-static-dynamic-or-framework-project-inside-another-project)