# Accessing storyboard from custom framework not working

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, uistoryboard

Hi I have to access storyboard from custom framework (**LoginUIModule, LoginUIModule have storyboard LoginScreen.storyboard**) in app delegate.
I removed Main storyboard from Main Interface and also removed name from Main storyboard file base name as well from .plist, but I getting an error

**reason: 'Could not find a storyboard named 'LoginScreen' in bundle NSBundle**

**Note:-** LoginUIModule is separate Module and I need to access it in my main **(OneAppllbs)** project which is a again separate module

The Code which I used in app delegate

```
import LoginUIModule

 self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "LoginScreen", bundle: nil)
    let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginUIModuleViewController") as? LoginUIModuleViewController
    self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Comment: `UIStoryboard: init(name: String, bundle storyboardBundleOrNil: Bundle?)` - **storyboardBundleOrNil** _The bundle containing the storyboard file and its related resources. If you specify nil, this method looks in the main bundle of the current application._ since LoginScreen is not in the main Bundle you need to pass in the LoginUIModule-Bundle. How to address this you might find in the Apple Documentation for Bundle. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/bundle

Comment: @DanielMarx thanks for you valuable comment and apple developer resources. got the solution and learn new concept as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need set `Bundle` to access Storyboard.

First create storyboardBundle with *Bundle Identifier* for framework;

```
let storyboardName = "LoginScreen"
let storyboardBundle = Bundle(for: LoginUIModuleViewController.self)
```

or referencing a class in framework:

```
let storyboardBundle = Bundle(identifier: "com.yourframework.id")
```

Then create storyboard with this bundle:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: storyboardName, bundle: storyboardBundle)
```

Comment: how can we push new view controller which is again in different module(DashboardModule) because navigation.push() is not working

Comment: If you can access a class you can use it whatever you want. Please ask this as new question with the details what you want to do and did so far.

Answer (score 0):

**Get storyboard from a framework**

Set `Storyboard ID` for `.storyboard`. For example frameworkStoryboardId

[[Access to Framework bundle]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67469835/4770877)

```
let frameworkStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "SomeViewController", bundle: frameworkBundle)

let frameworkViewController = frameworkStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "frameworkStoryboardId") as? SomeViewController
```