# How to "hide" framework usage

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

How is it possible to hide some framework usage (let's call it `HideFramework`), so it will not be exposed in IPA file?

I was trying to wrap code of that framework inside my own framework, but it still require dynamic linking my app with `HideFramework`.
Even if I embed `HideFramework` in my own framework

What I want to achieve: I want to hide any signs of `HideFramework` usage from IPA file

Comment: Are you really asking how to ***hide the fact that you are using someone else's Framework???***

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic frameworks can not hidden. You need to convert your framework into static library.
This is because "Static library" is linked at compile time, which does not change. Which is why it is not present in ipa file compare to frameworks which are available.

You can find detailed information here - [Library? Static? Dynamic? Or Framework? Project inside another project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15331056/library-static-dynamic-or-framework-project-inside-another-project)

Comment: The problem is that I don't have source code of `HideFramework` and it is dynamic. I'm looking a way to convert dynamic framework to static, but can't find solution. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: If it is a public framework and you don't have source code for that, why do want to hide?

Comment: I have requirements from client to do that :-)

Comment: I don't think that is possible