# Build a framework which can use only in one iOS app?

Tags: ios, frameworks

Is it possible to create a framework which only works on a specified app bundle identifier?

I want to prevent to reuse ur framework by shipping out my app source code / project which is using a selfmade framework

Answer (score 1):

If you ship source code, you cannot prevent the code from being reused. If you want to ship the compiled framework, you can use the approach described in the answer of Reinier Melian.

You could also consider creating a pure library instead of a framework. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15331056/library-static-dynamic-or-framework-project-inside-another-project) and [here](http://www.knowstack.com/framework-vs-library-cocoa-ios/) for the differences.